# Visual Studio 2010 Qt Add-in Cmake Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, cmake

I'm trying to use Cmake to start a new Qt Project inside Visual Studio 2010. I want to recreate the standard setup, as if you were just creating a new Qt project inside MSVS using the Qt Add-in. Since I only have limited knowledge of Cmake and the internet is running out of ideas I need your help. The reason why I want to do this is because I have an existing Visual Studio project and I need to add a GUI.
So what I did was creating a new Qt project inside Visual Studio with just the default Qt-Window. What do I need to do in the CmakeLists.txt to achieve the same results? Or is it easier not to try to remake the standard project and just use the .ui file from the Designer? Do I need to do the whole qt5_wrap_cpp, qt4_wrap_ui and so on stuff in the Cmake?
I've searched for a solution for about two days now and I'm still there where I started.

Thanks for your help and guidance

Comment: I create all of my Visual Studio Qt applications using CMake generated Visual Studio project files where I create the CMakeLists.txt file myself.

Comment: Here is some help for Qt5 (and cmake): http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html

Comment: There are also a few Qt examples in the vtk examples wiki. http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx#Qt You can look at the CMakeLists.txt from those examples to get some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I am also doing similar things, so I would like to share some views on it.

I created a project in QtCreator, with a project file `.pro`, `.h`, `.cpp`, `.ui` files. The qt project file `.pro` is for qmake. Then I transferred my project to MSVC. All I do is to transfer the `.h` `.cpp` `.ui` files to a new directory, and add a `CMakeList.txt` there.

If you have a existing Visual Studio project and you need to add a GUI, you can create a `.ui`in QtDesigner and add the `.ui` file to `CMakeList.txt`.

To create `CMakeList.txt`, you can go to the link in the comment above. Though I found the web quite hard to understand as a newbie. So basically, the CMakeList.txt would contain:

```
Follow the qt web for details when including the directories.
After that: 

SET( PROJECT_SRCS
     main.cpp)

SET( PROJECT_UIS                     //this is where you include your .ui files
     Resources/UI/myui.ui)

SET( PROJECT_MOC_HDRS
       mainWindow.h)

QT5_WRAP_UI( PROJECT_UIS_H            //wrap ui files
             ${PROJECT_UIS}
           )
QT5_WRAP_CPP( PROJECT_MOC_SRCS
              ${PROJECT_MOC_HDRS}
            )
ADD_EXECUTABLE( MRT_1JUL
                ${PROJECT_SRCS}
                ${PROJECT_UIS_H}
                ${PROJECT_MOC_SRCS}
```